# Rails with MySQL v.4.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mysql4

Is there any chance to make Rails application connect to old MySQL v4.1.20 server?

```
rails db
```

command works fine, but I cannot run the application.

When I generate new app with

```
rails new app_name -d mysql
```

I see the following in database.yml file:

> MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.

Which should mean I am able to use it.
However Rails Active Record uses MySQL v.5.0.2+ feature (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb):

```
# Make MySQL reject illegal values rather than truncating or blanking them, see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables
# If the user has provided another value for sql_mode, don't replace it.

    if strict_mode? && !variables.has_key?(:sql_mode)
      variables[:sql_mode] = 'STRICT_ALL_TABLES'
    end
```

Unfortunately I have nothing to do with old MySQL server version. I have to use it.

Comment: It might be more productive to simply update MySQL. In any case, "cannot run the application" is a near-useless statement that doesn't describe the problem.

Comment: @user2864740 I cannot update it. It is third-party application I have to work with.

Comment: @MikhailChuprynski Are you sure it's 4.1.2? That wasn't even a beta version, see [version history](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/news-4-1-x.html). More probably it's 4.1.20. But even that is dangerously old.

Comment: @VMai Server version: 4.1.20-community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
strict: false
```

to the connector settings in database.yml solved the problem.